# Compiling Hello World C++ Code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, powershell, visual-studio-code

I have a very simple hello world code as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to compile it in VSCode powershell terminal of Windows 10. I am using VS Community 2019.
Here is my directory structure:

[image]

When I do a `cl triplex.cpp` I get this:
[image]

but then at the next step when I try to run the program:
`triplex`

I am getting this error:
[image]

I have seen many posts with this error but none of them actually solved up my issue. Someone please help me getting out of this problem.

Comment: run `./triplex`

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 thanks it worked. And I am writing code in vs code (which is an editor) and compiling it in the terminal provided by vscode. I used vs community to install necessary packages.

Comment: If you have vs community 2019 perhaps you should use that for editting and building instead of vs code. It's a much richer environment.

Comment: I can't help but notice the first output image you posted (which should be text, not an image of text) contains the solution given to you here in its second line.

Comment: @chris which really doesn't do anything to ones used for GUI OS or older WIndows. That's those culturally familiar with Linux get it. And PowerShell is being too bash-ful :P

Comment: [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) != [Visual Studio Community 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @d4rk4ng31, It executed using `./triplex`. Thank you so much guys.

Comment: Also try using `& .\triplex\`

Comment: I see what's the difference between the two? Both of them executed successfully in my case.

Comment: That is the recommended official syntax for powershell.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple download mingw installer ,set its path in environment variable,for compiling in vscode just type command:-
g++ (name of file).cpp
2nd command :-
a.exe